# Assign click() to a child control in jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have the following html  element

```
<select id="selectStates" size="5" multiple="multiple" class="box">
    <option value="tx">Texas</option>
    <option value="ak">Alaska</option>
    <option value="ca">California</option>
    <option value="ws">Washington</option>
    <option value="tn">Tennessee</option>
</select>
```

And I have a `<map>`. It has 50  elements with ID's for starting from A0, A1, A2... A50 as following: (

extra line" href="#" coords="51,15,52,15,52,16,53,16,. . " />

I already have click event in a js file, which highlights the state when i click on it.

Now I want to highlight that particular state area in map when I click that state in a list box.

Right am trying to do as follows by assigning the click event of that state to a particular  in

```
$('#selectStates').find('#tn').click(function(e){
            $('#A51').click();
            });
```

But this doesn't seem to work.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: can you show the actual HTML code, it's not clear by what you wrote above what you're trying to do.

Comment: What do this click handlers for A0 - A50 look like? `.click()` will only fire handlers you made, not the default functionality.

Comment: If it's states don't you mean `A0 - A49` for 50 states ---- or is it `A1 - A50`?

Comment: Rocky, PLEASE use the code block to show your code. It's impossible to read without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do:

```
$("#selectStates").find("[value=tn]").select(function() {
   $("#A51").click()
})
```

better however, is this:

```
<select>
 <option value="tn" data-click-div="A51">TN</option>
</select>
```

single handler now:

```
$("#selectStates").change(function(evt) {
   var obj = "#" + jQuery(this).attr("data-click-div");
   jQuery(obj).click();
});
```

what I did here is add an attribute to the option to say which div to click. Everything, then, is done.

Comment: I thought that's what he wanted to do - when TN is selected, click A51

Comment: Maybe you're right, but OP says there's a map from A0 to A50, so I assumed OP wants the corresponding A-- to fire.... It is unclear from the example.

Comment: yeah, I know, it's not the best question out there, for sure.

Comment: The following seems to work in firefox: $("#selectStates").find("[value=tn]").select(function() {
   $("#A51").click()
})

Comment: The following seems to work in firefox but not in IE: $("#selectStates").find("[value=tn]").select(function() { $("#A51").click() }) ... IS THERE ANY PARTICULAR REASON?

Comment: @Rocky - So do you want the corresponding map element's `click` triggered? If so, it'd be easier to rename the `id` of the map elements. - See my answer for a suggestion.

Comment: are you seeing anything in terms of errors? can you debug this? try to ask more SPECIFIC questions, with more information to illustrate your point.

Comment: @Rocky - `.select()` is limited to `<input type="text">` fields and `<textarea>` boxes according to the documentation ==> http://api.jquery.com/select/ .... so you shouldn't count on it working at all. You should be using `.click()`.

Comment: @Rocky - Whoops. You should be putting the click directly on `#selectStates` since that's what gets the value! That causes the error... IE is just more of  a stickler ==> http://jsfiddle.net/XMFHY/

Answer (score 2):

Using find("#tn") will not work. `#` is indicative of an id, but you are searching for a value. You need to search for the attribute `value`.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the click to the select and check is value.

Example:

```
$("#selectStates").click (function() {
   switch (this.value) {
     case "tx":
       //do something
       break;
     case "ak":
       //do something
       break;
     case "ca":
       //do something
       break;
     case "ws":
       //do something
       break;
     case "tn":
       //do something
       break;
   }
})
```

Comment: This seems quite painful (I'm assuming 50 states).

Comment: @Peter what do you want the click event to do? are they different for each state or the same for all?

Comment: OP seems a little unclear on it. It sounds like there are 50 map elements with ids A0 - A49. This is why I suggested renaming the map elements. ---- This will definitely work, and +1 for clarifying that the value should taken from the `select` and not the `option` ----------------------- I would suggest ` switch (this.value) {`

Comment: @Peter...I get the suggestion of using this.value but since it is a select element and this references the DOM object wouldn't it be this.options(this.selectedIndex).value

Comment: In that context, `$("#selectStates").val()` is exactly the same as `$(this).val()` which is a jQuery method that simply fetches `this.value`, so you might as well use `this.value` instead of running around the block once before fetching it. -------- In `$("#selectStates").click...`, `$(this)` is the jQuery object `$("#selectStates")` and `this` is the DOM element with the id `selectStates`.

Answer (score 1):

**You must check the value of the `select` element and not the `option` elements. You should also put the click handler on the `select` element. If you do not do this, the code will not work in IE.**

I think you should make a map with elements A and then the state, so `Atn`, `Atx`, etc.

Then you can fire the click on the appropriate map element using:

```
$("#selectStates").click(function() {
   $("#A" + this.value).click();
});
```

### [Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XMFHY/)

Note: Ninja Dude pointed out in the comments that **[`.select()`](http://api.jquery.com/select/)** doesn't work in this case, so I use **[`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)** like in the OP, since **[`.select()`](http://api.jquery.com/select/)** is limited to `<input type="text">` fields and `<textarea>` boxes. The select event is sent to an element when the user makes a text selection inside it.

Comment: @Ninja - Yes, but it looks like click does work. `.select()` is limited to `<input type="text">` fields and `<textarea>` boxes.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("option[value=tn]")
```

because the specific option you are targeting does not have the `id="tn"`

Comment: This will not work in IE if you check for the value with `this.value`, since the `select` element gets the value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this

```
$(function() {
  $('#selectStates > *').click(function(e){
    alert('you clicked : ' +this.value);
  });
});
```

### [see it in Action](http://jsbin.com/ecace5)

Comment: `$(#selectStates option)"` is a little more descriptive.

Comment: well, I don't think `> *` isn't  bad. Basically a select tag consists of option tags, so this selector `> *` aims at option elements only, afaik :)

Comment: Additionally, the `option` elements should not be getting a click handler, since the value is assigned to the `select` element. The above will not work in IE due to this.

Comment: sorry, bit sleepy. will test it latter. have a Good day !! BTW I had an exam tomorrow, plz wish me best of luck.Thanks :)