# Onclick in select not working in IE

Tags: javascript, select, onclick

Am a bit new to javascript. This question might sound a bit too silly, but I'm not able to figure it out **why the following doesn't work in IE and works in firefox..**

```
<select multiple="multiple">
 <option value="tx" onClick="alert('tx');">Texas</option>
 <option value="ak" onClick="alert('ak');">Alaska</option>
 <option value="ca" onClick="alert('ca');">California</option>
 <option value="ws" onClick="alert('ws');">Washington</option>
 <option value="tn" onClick="alert('tn');">Tennessee</option>
</select>
```

The alert doesn't come up in IE (I'm using IE8). But it works in firefox!!!!!

Comment: That has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign click() to a child control in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970564/assign-click-to-a-child-control-in-jquery)

Comment: I'm sorry I put up the wrong heading in question. Its a simple html select element and javascript to invoke click event which does not work in ie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_option.asp), the option tag does support an onclick attribute.  I tried with with bottom of the barrel IE6 and this doesn't seem to be the case.

The simplest way to do this would be:

```
<select multiple="multiple" onchange="alert(this.value);">
 <option value="tx">Texas</option>
 <option value="ak">Alaska</option>
 <option value="ca">California</option>
 <option value="ws">Washington</option>
 <option value="tn">Tennessee</option>
</select>
```

This is not exactly what you are after, but should be pretty close.

**EDITS**

It would just take more work:

```
<select multiple="multiple" onchange="
    switch (this.value){
      case 'tx': funcOne(); break;
      case 'ak': funcTwo(); break;
      etc...
   }
 ">
 <option value="tx">Texas</option>
 <option value="ak">Alaska</option>
 <option value="ca">California</option>
 <option value="ws">Washington</option>
 <option value="tn">Tennessee</option>
</select>
```

At this point it would be appropriate to wrap the onchange into a function in a js file instead of embedding it in the html.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that looks better. But what if I need to assign different functions for different options? I cant make this work right?

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. That should do it I guess

Answer (score 6):

I would use the onchange event:

```
<select multiple="multiple" onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
 <option value="tx">Texas</option>
 <option value="ak">Alaska</option>
 <option value="ca">California</option>
 <option value="ws">Washington</option>
 <option value="tn">Tennessee</option>
</select>
```

Although Daniel Mendel's solution is perfectly valid.

Comment: Its great when I have a single function to be called. But what if I need to assign different functions for different options?

Comment: That's what the selectedIndex will tell you. You can get the actual option element from that and do something different with it *within the same function*. That is a feature, not a drawback. For simplicity (and following your lead) I put the entire handler in the event listener attribute, but really you would simply pass "this" to an external function. Or use jQuery and assign it a function literal.

Comment: change does not fire until the select loses focus, some browsers do fire it as you select with up/down arrows

Comment: @Juan Mendes: The example I gave fires on all flavors of change, including click and up/down arrows, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is because IE doesn't register a click event when you select a new option in a select field (guessing).  Instead, you should use the onBlur event (and put the code into your javascript instead) like so (assuming jQuery):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select#state').bind('blur', function(){
      alert(this.val());
    });
  });
</script>

<select id='state' multiple="multiple">
  <option value="tx">Texas</option>
  <option value="ak">Alaska</option>
  <option value="ca">California</option>
  <option value="ws">Washington</option>
  <option value="tn">Tennessee</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I entered the question wrong. I dont have any jquery at all. COnsidering simple javascript and html select.. Is there a way to make it work in IE?

Comment: Understood, the answer by Robusto is the most direct, valid, straight javascript solution for the code you posted.