# Select option, on click event not working in IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

This is the HTML code :

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="selectPartType">
      <option value = 'FG'>FG</option>
      <option value = 'SFG'>SFG</option>
      <option value = 'RM'>RM</option>
</select>
```

JQuery click event :

```
$('select option').on('click', function (event) {           
            alert('Hello');           
});
```

This code is not working in IE 11, but working in google crome and firefox. Please suggest any solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Onclick in select not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988938/onclick-in-select-not-working-in-ie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be listening to the `change` event. It is fired when any of the options is selected/deselected.

Also, instead of binding to `select option`, you should bind to `select` for the `change` event.

```js
$('select').on('change', function (event) {           
      alert('Hello');           
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" id="selectPartType">
      <option value = 'FG'>FG</option>
      <option value = 'SFG'>SFG</option>
      <option value = 'RM'>RM</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The value of select element can be accessed by `$(this).val()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use correct ID identifier # in the jQuery selector.
Try this:

```
$('#selectPartType').on('click', function (event) {           
  alert('Hello');           
});
```

Or this:

```
$('#selectPartType').on('change', function (event) {           
  alert('Hello');           
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same in plain JavaScript to avoid any JQuery when considering IE.

```js
document.getElementById('selectPartType').onchange = function() {
  alert("Hello!");
}
```

```html
<select multiple id="selectPartType">
      <option value = 'FG'>FG</option>
      <option value = 'SFG'>SFG</option>
      <option value = 'RM'>RM</option>
</select>
```